# How do I prevent labeling outside of the current atlas feature polygon?

Tags: qgis, labeling, atlas

I want to create an atlas which is based on region polygons. I use inverted polygons and rule based styles (inverted polygons) for the polygon layer with the rule  `$id  = @atlas_featureid` which works fine. I have also a point layer and the features of the point layer are not shown due to the inverted polygons but their labels are shown. I want to prevent the labels outside of the current atlas feature polygon. Which expression should I use for the rule-based-labeling? I found this post ([Filtering out labels surrounding active feature in Atlas](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/316498/filtering-out-labels-surrounding-active-feature-in-atlas)) and tried the suggested rule-based filtering expressions but it didn't work for me.

[image]

Comment: Please elaborate "tried the suggested rule-based filtering expressions but it didn't work" a little more. Which of the solutions and how did you set it up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Via data defined override:**

Go to "Labels" --> "Rendering" --> "Show label" --> "Data defined override" of your point-layer and insert `intersects($geometry,@atlas_geometry)` as expression as shown below:

[image]

**Or via Rule Based Labeling:**

Go to "Labels" --> "Rule-Based Labeling" of your point-layer and set up one rule with an expression like this: `intersects($geometry,@atlas_geometry)`

[image]

**Both will lead to this label-behavior in print layout:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly the expression I needed!