# Labeling only one object in layout using ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling

I have a layout map in ArcGIS. I would like to show the center Object label in layout ArcGIS. if you see sample layout in below. All the objects are labeled.
How can I delete all labeling, unlike center objects be labeled?
[image]

Comment: If this is a one time map you could use a rule to limit the label to the one feature by an expression.  If this is instead part of a Map Atlas then see some of the suggestions here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/316498/filtering-out-labels-surrounding-active-feature-in-atlas or here: https://gist.github.com/rbanick/cddc75f6398ddbef5cee

Comment: I just show lable o object in center layout no other object.

Comment: I display an object that it is full and another object is uncompleted don't display.

Comment: Are you using ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap to try to do this?