# Making map book (Atlas) with filter in QGIS

Tags: qgis, 3d, atlas, map-book, 2d

In QGIS, I want to make a map book (Atlas) with only buildings but only one building showing up per page. So essentially a filter. I am not sure how to go about this.

Also, is it possible to have two map books on one layout? We have 2D and 3D buildings we would want to run this on. OR is there a way to sync the 2D and 3D views? This was not a capability in ESRI when it came to the layout only while viewing.

Can this be done in QGIS?

For some clarification see below:

[image]

I just want one polygon to show up that matches the `"PAR_PIN"` that is labelling each page.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: does https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/316498/filtering-out-labels-surrounding-active-feature-in-atlas help?

Comment: So I am currently trying to use the Filter with option and using the expression @id = "PAR_PIN". The "PAR_PIN" field is what each page will be based on. Possibly the expression I am using is incorrect since I get an error that nothing comes of the expression.

Comment: Try https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/316542/79

Comment: It doesn't seem like those expressions shown in the link work in this case

Comment: please use the [edit] button to update your question with the filter(s) you have tried `$id = @atlas_featureid` should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under Layer styling, you need to use rule-based styling and write the expression

```
$id=@atlas_featureid
```

[image]

It will look like this:

[image]

Now from the Atlas configuration,

- Select the coverage layer
- Select the building `id` field for the `Page name`
- Enable Atlas from the button located in the main toolbar
- Only the polygon(s) corresponding to the building id will be shown.

[image]

Here is the output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @ahmadhanb for the visuals! I am a visual learner so this helped tremendously. I was actually able to get this to work by going into Item Properties, Clipping settings, and check off Clip to atlas feature. I really appreciate your response and will save it for future use!

Comment: @Alex You are welcome. If the answer helps you to solve the problem, please accept it so that it can help others.

Comment: Yes I will! I have another question...do you know if an atlas can be generated on a 3D layer? I am trying to do this and when I click "Generate" the view doesn't zoom to the building.

Comment: @Alex I did not use Atlas on a 3D layer. If you want to know how to generate Atlas on a 3D layer, it is better to ask a new question.